# Select columns in data.table based on logical vector

Tags: r, data.table, logical-operators

Let's say I have the following data.frame and the following data.table:

```
DF = data.frame(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

With a data.frame, I can select columns based on a logical vector as follows:

```
DF[,c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)]
```

The result is:

```
  x y
1 a 1
2 a 3
3 a 6
4 b 1
5 b 3
6 b 6
7 c 1
8 c 3
9 c 6
```

However

```
DT[,c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)]
```

leads to:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Update 2020-04-22

In current CRAN version of `data.table`, `DT[ , c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]` would work -- no need for `with=FALSE`. Leaving this older answer here for posterity:

---

We need `with=FALSE`

```
DT[, c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), with=FALSE]
```

Based on the documentation in `?data.table`

> By default with=TRUE and j is evaluated within the frame of x; column
>   names can be used as variables. When with=FALSE j is a character
>   vector of column names or a numeric vector of column positions to
>   select, and the value returned is always a data.table. with=FALSE is
>   often useful in data.table to select columns dynamically.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for quoting the explanation from the doc.

Comment: sorry, just a little q on this as well: If I want to set these columns to some value, e.g. `NA`, what is the best way to do it? Or should I make a new q?

Comment: @user3032689  If you want to set the first two columns to NA, there are different ways to do it, a compact one is `DT[, (1:2) := NA]`

Comment: I'm using 4.1.0 installed 5/18/2021 and I still need `with=F`